# Sending Image to server with parameters in Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire

I am trying to send Image on the server with `json` parameter using Alamofire. But on the server they are able to receive the image but not the `Json` i am sending.  Below is the code that i am using:

```
let parameters: [String : String] = [
            "preferredVenueType": "club",
            "userId": "1"
        ]
let urlRequest = urlRequestWithComponents(baseURL + uploadImage, parameters: parameters , imageData: imageData!)
upload(urlRequest.0, data: urlRequest.1)
 .progress { (bytesWritten, totalBytesWritten,   totalBytesExpectedToWrite) in
 //print("\(totalBytesWritten) / \(totalBytesExpectedToWrite)")
 }
.responseJSON {response in
                    if let JSON = response.result.value {
                        print("JSON: \(JSON)")
 }




func urlRequestWithComponents(urlString:String, parameters:Dictionary<String, String>, imageData:NSData) -> (URLRequestConvertible, NSData) {

        // create url request to send
        let mutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: urlString)!)
        mutableURLRequest.HTTPMethod = Method.POST.rawValue
        let boundaryConstant = "myRandomBoundary12345";
        let contentType = "multipart/form-data;boundary="+boundaryConstant
        mutableURLRequest.setValue(contentType, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

       // mutableURLRequest.HTTPBody = jsonData


        // create upload data to send
        let uploadData = NSMutableData()

        // add image
        uploadData.appendData("\r\n--\(boundaryConstant)\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
        uploadData.appendData("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"profileImage\"; filename=\"profileImage.png\"\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
        uploadData.appendData("Content-Type: image/png\r\n\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
        uploadData.appendData(imageData)

        // add parameters
        for (key, value) in parameters {
            uploadData.appendData("\r\n--\(boundaryConstant)\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
            uploadData.appendData("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"\r\n\r\n\(value)".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
          //  uploadData.appendData("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"json\"\r\n\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)

                        }
        uploadData.appendData("\r\n--\(boundaryConstant)--\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)



        // return URLRequestConvertible and NSData
        return (ParameterEncoding.URL.encode(mutableURLRequest, parameters: nil).0, uploadData)

    }
```

I am getting error message in response as they are unable to receive the `JSON` data along with the image file.

Comment: did you checked [alamo fire multipart upload](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#user-content-uploading-multipartformdata)?

Comment: @the_UB I checked this also but still not working...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my Problem by sending parameters as a `JSON String` instead of key value pairs.

```
 let parameters: [String : String] = [
            "preferredVenueType": prameterText,
            "userId": userId,
        ]
         var theJSONText : NSString  = ""

        do {
            let theJSONData = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(
                parameters ,
                options: NSJSONWritingOptions(rawValue: 0))
            theJSONText = NSString(data: theJSONData,
                encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding)!
            // due to some reason NSUTF8StringEncoding was not working so i used ASCII encoding
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error)
        }
```

And while sending it to server i used

```
let uploadData = NSMutableData()

        uploadData.appendData("--\(boundaryConstant)\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
        uploadData.appendData("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"json\"\r\n\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
        uploadData.appendData("\(theJSONText)\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
```

After sending parameters as a `JSON String` the data was successfully uploaded to server.

Comment: i am getting same issue could not upload image . i want to try your demo but getting Use of undeclared type 'URLRequestConvertible'.  and one request if possible can you give full code for this ? on drive or email or other way which you preferred.

Comment: @jay:  Hi, Send me your email id i will send you the full code related to the image upload.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I don't have knowledge on swift. But according to your issue, the server receiving image that means url is correct. so

1) first check the data your sending. may be your sending wrong type of data.
   eg: server side {dictionary[dictionary]}, your sending{dictionary} like this.

2)check the header fields.

3)check the name of header field objects and keys.(capital or small) each   and every letter.

4)finally add the below code in your project .plist files. Add to each and every plist in your project.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
 </dict>
```

to add this, right click on .plist , then open it as source code.copy the above lines and past the lines  before `"</dict></plist>"` at the end.

just try this.. I am not sure about this ,it will be useful.